# Pulling data from a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a problem with pulling the words from a string or list.

I have a string :

```
example = "name, name, data, test, name, john, password, sometex, port, someport"
```

As you can notice, there are 3 words with value of `name`.
And the 3rd `name` has a value right next to it (`john`), next is `password` which has the `sometext` value right after it, and there is `port` which has a value right after the comma again (`someport`).
The thing is, the values are different every time, so they're not hard coded. And also, the index of the keys can be different. So basically I only know the key names, and the values are right next to them.

The question is, is there a way to pull the values only, maybe to turn this into a dict or a list for easier manipulation. Or maybe using a regex?

First two words `name` are also there, which don't have a value at all, they're just there and I don't need them at all.

Comment: You could just split the string by commas and use the parity of the index (even vs odd) to determine key vs value.

Comment: I edited my question so you can take a look one more time. Thanks

Comment: how to identify the values that are not needed for example this `data, test` can we consider this or not?

Comment: Actually the 'not needed' values are just first and the second word. I just need to get the key words (name, password, port) but ignoring the first two words for example. And the values are right next to every key word

Comment: does string always have the same order?

Comment: Not always - but i am not 100% sure since it's not tested yet. But anyways, few first words are not important at all

Comment: you have to provide correct details how the program will know few words?

Comment: There is exact output which is returned every time, and in every case first 2 words are the same as the first key which i need

Comment: for the input you posted this will work `{example[idx]: example[idx + 1] for idx in range(4, len(example), 2) if idx + 1 < len(example)}` split the string `example = example.split(',')`

Comment: The point is - 'asd',  'bsb', 'cmc', 'asd', 'value1', 'key2', 'value2', 'key3', 'value3'

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow. Feel free to post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want name because it's consecutive duplicates.  This code would delete any consecutive duplicates and make a dict out of the rest.

If this is not the case, then your problem is not solvable, as we would have no way of knowing which ones to keep and which ones to drop.

```
example = "name, name, data, test, name, john, password, sometex, port, someport"
example = example.split(', ')
c = []

for x in range(1,len(example)):
    if example[x]==example[x-1]:
        c.append(x)
        
for x in c:
    del example[x-1: x+1]
    
dict(zip(example[0::2], example[1::2]))
```

Or the following will produce the same result, for less obvious reasons, mainly that `'name':'name'` will be overwritten by `'name':'john'` during the zip.  Hardly likely this will hold to be true in all scenarios.

```
    example = "name, name, data, test, name, john, password, sometex, port, someport"
    example = example.split(', ')
    dict(zip(example[0::2], example[1::2]))
```

Output

```
{'data': 'test', 'name': 'john', 'password': 'sometex', 'port': 'someport'}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it and mark it depending on the result.

Answer (score -2):

How about this code

```
dict1={}
dict['name'] =example.split(', ')[5]
dict['password'] =example.split(', ')[7]
dict['port'] =example.split(', ')[9]
```

Comment: I edited my answer so you can take a look one more time. Is the answer still the same?

Comment: don't you mean dict1?